# simple pattern rule issue with GNU make

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to write a very simple pattern rule with GNU make. The goal is to deduce a sequence of steps (deps, fetch, install, etc) from a single target, for example "fsl.Linux";

```
kanbing@majapahit:/tmp$ cat Makefile

%.Linux : %.Linux.deps

fsl.Linux.deps:
        @echo hit rule fsl.Linux.deps
        @echo

kanbing@majapahit:/tmp$ make fsl.Linux.deps ; make fsl.Linux
hit rule fsl.Linux.deps

make: *** No rule to make target 'fsl.Linux'.  Stop.

kanbing@majapahit:/tmp$
```

What am I missing here ? First target pre-requisite is obviously not a file, but this should work, isn't it ?

Comment: This has something to do with `%.Linux` not having a recipe. If I add a dummy recipe, e.g. `@true`, then it works.

Comment: See ["Canceling Implicit Rules"](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Canceling-Rules).  There's almost certainly a dupe for this.

Comment: Many thanks for the answers ! indeed, adding any dummy recipe like @echo to the  %.Linux target solved the issue !